# Наложение изображения поверх border

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Вокруг дива идёт border, нужно что бы сверху на border наложить [изображение] Как это можно сделать?

[image]

Comment: @Jdk2se, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так http://jsfiddle.net/g8fm6n9h/

HTML

```
<div class="block">   
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.block{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
}
.block div{
    position: absolute;   
}
.top, .bottom{
    background: #000;
    left: 0;   
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.top{
    background: #000;
    top: 0;   
}
.bottom{
    background: #00f;
    bottom: 0;     
}

.right, .left{   
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
}
.right{
    background: #f00;
    right: 0;    
}
.left{
    background: #c00;
    left: 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно изображение только на `border`, то можно использовать свойство [`border-image`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-image) для блока

Comment: Тоже думал в сторону border-image. Но нужно, чтобы вокруг всего блока рамка была dashed, а в верху по середине перекрывалась картинкой. Сейчас пробую вывести картинку в div и сдвинуть в верх position:absolute;